# How do I check the contents of an array?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to check if a char array contains all `'0'`s.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
char array[8];
// ...
if (array == {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'})
   // do something
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7):

This

```
array == {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'}
```

is definitely wrong, and surely not compiling.

You can compare the values with `memcmp()` like this

```
int allZeroes = (memcmp(array, "00000000", 8) == 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

In fact

```
array == {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'}
```

is not allowed, you cannot compare arrays like this. Rather, do it in a loop:

```
int row_is_all_zeroes(char arr[8])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    if (arr[i] != '0')
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

If you want a more elegant solution, have a look at iharob or Sourav's answers

Answer (score 5):

```
{'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'}
```

is called (and used as) a *brace enclosed* initializer list. This cannot be used for *comparison* anywhere.

You can make use of [`memcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp) to achieve this in an *elegant* way.

Pseudo-code

```
if (!memcmp(array, "00000000", 8))
{
   break;
}
```

Comment: Much thanks Mr. @Dukeling for taking the charge to make the question and _all_ the answers easily understandable and more useful . Kudos !!